# how to match markdown block code between 3 grave accent

Tags: javascript, regex, qregularexpression

- i know that this a common question but i searched a lot and not found what i need to
- i'm trying to create simple markdown plug but i can't match the block code i tried this regex
  `` /(^\`{3}[\w|\W]+\`{3})/gm `` but it's get me every thing between the first and last grave accent and if there's anothe block code it's add them all inside one
- for example the following string

````
 ``` 
  block code 
  word1
  word2
 ```

word without grave accent and it is will match it too

 ```
  another block code
  word1
  word2
  - it's will match it as part of the first block code
 ```

"""
some text after the grave accent text
word1
word2
"""`
````

- this regex result is like the following array

````
0: "``` \nblock code\nword1\nword2\n```\n\nword without grave accent and it's will match it too\n\n```\nanother block code\nword1\nword2\n- it's will match it as part of the first block code\n```"
length: 1
````

- and i want it to match then like this

````
0: "``` \nblock code\nword1\nword2\n```"
1: "```\nanother block code\nword1\nword2\n- it's will match it as part of the first block code\n```"
length: 2
````

- I'm not good enough at regex so i hope someone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to lazily match your `+` quantifier: `` (\`{3}[\w|\W]+?\`{3}) ``
The `+?` will try to match one or more times with as few characters as possible, ensuring it doesn't greedily take up everything between your `` \`{3} ``s. Quantifiers are greedy by default.

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/v3gouJ/1)

Here's some [more reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) on lazy vs greedy.

Comment: Thank you regular expression is looking like a nightmare

Comment: @JS_INF Regular expressions are great! Sometimes they take a bit of fiddling to get it right, but they're really powerful when you've got a hang on some of the advanced features.

Comment: That's cool i will try to improve myself on it ... Thanks